Add public method in ClientCodegen to be used in mustache
I have forked the openAPI generator aiming to tweak the Swift5ClientCodegen. So far, I have successfully modified some methods to change how some classes and property names are formatted. For instance, if property is "imageUrl" then it would be formatted to "imageURL".
I also want to introduce a way (maybe methods but not sure if that's the best apporach) to provide some values that can be used in the mustache templates.
One of these values needs to figure out if there has been any properties escaped so it can be used like that:
...
{{#hasEscapedPropertyNames}}
// MARK: - Decodable

extension {{{classname}}}: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: {{#hasVars}}String, {{/hasVars}}CodingKey {
        {{#allVars}}
        case {{{name}}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-codegen-escaped-property-name}} = "{{{baseName}}}"{{/vendorExtensions.x-codegen-escaped-property-name}}
        {{/allVars}}
    }
}
{{/hasEscapedPropertyNames}}

My questions are:

Which one is the best approach to define custom values to be used in mustache templates?
How can figure out if a property name has been escaped?

I have very basic knowledge on the project and I apologise if something doesn't make sense

Apparently, in Swift5ClientCodegen line 1127 the x-codegen-has-escaped-property-names is added to specify if there has been escaped property names.
So you can modify the mustache file with the following
...
{{#vendorExtensions.x-codegen-has-escaped-property-names}}

// MARK: - Decodable

extension {{{classname}}}: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: {{#hasVars}}String, {{/hasVars}}CodingKey {
        {{#allVars}}
        case {{{name}}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-codegen-escaped-property-name}} = "{{{baseName}}}"{{/vendorExtensions.x-codegen-escaped-property-name}}
        {{/allVars}}
    }
}
{{/vendorExtensions.x-codegen-has-escaped-property-names}} 
...

